# Displaying a string in an int array (for validation check)

Tags: java, arrays, string, validation

I'm using a for loop as a form of validation check to make sure the input for the variable stScore is a number over 0 and under or equal to 100, example shown here, if the input isn't correct, the score parameter will be shown as 0:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    if ((stScore[i] > 0 && stScore[i] <= 100))
        score[i] = stScore[i];
    else
        score[i] = 0;
```

My question is if there is any way to display a string (to say something like error!) in place of that 0 instead? Of course at the base of things you can't have an int array include a string, but I was wondering if there is a workaround for this.
Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet does not print anything at all.

Comment: it's all part of a larger class.

Comment: As an alternative to the "special value" answers: create a paralllel boolean array, containing `true` for valid entries and `false` for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately you cannot :(. But we usually don't use 0 as an error code. In these situations I use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to indicate an error.

So your code will be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    if ((stScore[i] > 0 && stScore[i] <= 100))
        score[i] = stScore[i];
    else
        score[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

I suggest you not to use 0. Because 0, when it is an exit code, it usually means "OK". In C++, the `main` method returns 0 when the program exits with no errors. Alternatively, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` can be used as well.

**For more readable code**, you can declare a constant called `ERROR`:

```
final int ERROR = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use 0 simply because it is contiguous with the valid range.  It looks like it's a valid state rather than an error state.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to ascribe some magic meaning to a particular `int` value that would never otherwise occur in your data. E.g., declare a constant:

```
private static final int INVALID_SCORE = -1;
```

Use it both when assigning:

```
if ((stScore[i] > 0 && stScore[i] <= 100))
    score[i] = stScore[i];
else
    score[i] = INVALID_SCORE;
```

And when printing:

```
System.out.println(score[i] != INVALID_SCORE ? score[i] : "Invalid score!");
```

The disadvantage is that it will cause problems if you forget to treat the value specially in later code that uses the data.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to set any invalid inputs to -1. Then on output you could have an if statement the checks for the error value (-1) and outputs an appropriate error message.

It's bad practice to mix types in any sort of collection; avoid it whenever possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("your score is below zero");
```

That would seem to be appropriate

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, because this should be something that is expected to happen once in a while. Throwing an exception will make the valid scores in the array not assigned.

Comment: Just offering up another option.  If the goal is to zero out the bad data, then an exception would be wrong.  If bad data is an error condition, then a score outside the acceptable bounds, by definition is an illegal argument.  You pass that error back to whatever passed the value in, and let the caller deal with it, and re-run the routine if necessary.